# Invalid hook call, Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef'), Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') while using Routes, Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUmAm.png)I am creating React App and everything was ok until I tried to connect the pages using Routes and Route

I got error:

- “Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')” or ‘useContext’ in google chrome
- “null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useRef')” in Safari
- “Invalid hook call” in console in google chrome

(I don't use any useRef, use Context)

Imports work well beacause when I import f.e. only HomePage in App function it works. Problems appears when I try use Routes, Route

Any ideas why and how to solve it?

in App.jsx I got

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                    <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

in index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And question about script in index.html

```
<body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Did I do it correctly? At first I had type="module" but I got an error in the browser console:
"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
At the beginning I changed "module" to "text/html", but it implements js/jsx so this html does not fit my logic here.

I feel like I've already looked through the entire internet, but I can't figure out what it's all about and how to improve it.

The problem appeared when Routes, Route was introduced (I mean, I try to introduce).

Any ideas, tips, solutions? Or maybe there is another way to do it?

Or maybe I have the wrong packages installed and/or in a wrong way? What should I install, where and how?

(screenshot of files menu at the beginning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is at index.js, you need to add the `BrowserRouter`, that allows router works. Here you have an example for your index.js.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**EDIT 1**

After your comment, this is the `App.js` file that I have:

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT 2**

This is how my project looks

[image]

And this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ReactTest3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

You say that you have two node_modules folders, that is not correct, I think that project is corrupt because of different folders and npm installation.

**These are the steps that I wrote to test your project.**

1. npx create-react-app ReactTest3
2. cd ReactTest3 and npm start (This is just to check the react
   installation)
3. Added both components (HomePage and AboutPage)
4. Create some test text for both, here you have an example:
5. `import React from 'react'

   export const HomePage = () => {
   return (
   Hello from Home
   )
   }`
6. npm i react-router-dom
7. Changed the App.js code to be able to use routes (Example is on Edit 1)
8. Changed the index.js code to be able to use routes (Example is on the first answer)
9. It works!
10. If this does not work for you, I recommend to go to the React Router and try that example. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: I tried this version too, still doesn't work. There are the same errors

Comment: I have tested your code and it works on my computer. I just deleted the <Router> component, for what do you want it? If I use it, I have this error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.

Comment: Yes, I edited code in the same way as you did in App and index, but there are still the same errors  how does it work for you? This is not the first time it doesn't work for me, but when I consult my code with someone, it works for the other person. and I started this project again and still get the same errors

Comment: Hmmm, this in interesting, I have tried more options but all work. If this is not your first time with the problem, this could be a problem with the installation of the react or npm packages maybe, to be honest, I am not an expert with that, let's wait a bit to see if someone can help both of us.

Comment: What versions of dependencies do you have? (react, react dom etc., node version) and how your jsons looks like? What do you have in jsons and in what version? Maybe here is the problem (something didn't work for me once because it was too new version).
 + at the beginning of my question I upload a ss of file menu. I see there node_moudules, json, json in two places - outside whole project folder (this is list: project folder, node_modules, json, json) and inside whole project folder (this is: node_modules (again?), public, src, .gitignore, json, json, readme). I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: And how you process of creating react app looks like? What do you do? In vsc terminal/console. And what packages do you install?

Comment: All answered on the main answer, hope it helps, let me know.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I did it once again step by step just like you. Doubled node_modules and jsons must have been a problem

Comment: Yes! I'm very happy to hear it. Doubled node_modules seemed like a problem. Now you can always check this post to create it correctly :)